# Problemas de recepción de caracteres ascii con textview-Android

Tags: android, textview

Estoy haciendo pruebas de recepción de datos usando el puerto USB de mi dispositivo Android y para ello estoy usando este [codigo](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android), aparentemente los datos están llegando correctamente:

codigo de recepcion

```
    private final SerialInputOutputManager.Listener mListener =
        new SerialInputOutputManager.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onRunError(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Runner stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewData(final byte[] data) {
        SerialConsoleActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SerialConsoleActivity.this.updateReceivedData(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Codigo de visualizacion en el textview

```
    private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) {
    String s = new String(data);
    mDumpTextView.append(s);
    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mDumpTextView.getBottom());
}
```

pero por algún motivo los caracteres ocultos \r y \n (retorno de carro y cambio de linea) son eliminados por el textview o este tipo de formulario no acepta este tipo de caracteres, alguien me podria decir como puedo resolver esto?

Gracias

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate the question.

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: traduce también el título de la pregunta y añade el código mínimo necesario para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte